# How to list all OpenSSH supported authentication methods?

Tags: ssh

I am running Debian Linux jessie with OpenSSH version 6.7. I use the `AuthenticationMethods` directive in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. I know that these strings are recognized by `AuthenticationMethods`:

```
keyboard-interactive
gssapi-with-mic
password
publickey
```

Where can I find a list of *all* the valid strings that can be used with `AuthenticationMethods`? (Such a list is not in the man page for `sshd_config`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't documented very clearly (or at all). But here's what I was able to find. In OpenSSH 6.2, there were [only 4 methods](https://lwn.net/Articles/544640/)

> There are just four allowable methods: publickey, password, hostbased, and keyboard-interactive.

Others have felt the need for [more documentation](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2453) as well. See [Attachment 3045](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/attachment.cgi?id=3045&action=diff) which states for OpenSSH 7.5:

> The available authentication methods are: gssapi-with-mic, hostbased, keyboard-interactive, none (used for access to password-less accounts when PermitEmptyPassword  is enabled),, password, and publickey.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It looks like the documentation of methods allowable in `AuthenticationMethods` made it into version 7.6: [OpenSSH 7.6 release notes](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.6).

Answer (score 6):

There isn't a way … over the network … to list ALL the active methods of authentications of OpenSSH ... in advance … ever: You are challenged to only the first one then the next …

this is a security feature.  You want to know? Look at the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` directly on that server. Oh, you can’t? That’s security by design.

So, I'll expand the list even further than what the official OpenSSL documentation covered as I've been code-reviewing OpenSSH for some time.

The available authentication methods are:

- "`gssapi-with-mic`",
- "`hostbased`",
- "`keyboard-interactive`",
- "`none`" (used for access to password-less accounts when `PermitEmptyPassword` is enabled),
- "`password`" and
- "`publickey`".

`AuthenticationMethods` specifies the authentication methods that must be successfully completed for a user to be granted access.  This option must be followed by one or more lists of comma-separated authentication method names, or by the single string `any` to indicate the default behavior of accepting any single authentication method.  If the default is overridden, then successful authentication requires completion of every method in at least one of these lists.

### Pubkey Authentication

For example,

```
AuthenticationMethods publickey,password publickey,keyboard-interactive
```

would require the user to complete public key authentication, followed by either password or keyboard interactive authentication.  Only methods that are next in one or more lists are offered at each stage, so for this example it would not be possible to attempt `password` or `keyboard-interactive` authentication before public key.

## Keyboard Interactive Authentication

For keyboard interactive authentication it is also
possible to restrict authentication to a specific
device by appending a colon followed by the device
identifier `bsdauth` or `pam` depending on the server
configuration.  For example,

```
AuthenticationMethods keyboard-interactive:bsdauth
```

would restrict keyboard interactive authentication to the `bsdauth` device.

## Multiple Pubkey Authentication

If the publickey method is listed more than once, `sshd(8)` verifies that keys that have been used successfully are not reused for subsequent authentications.

For example,

```
AuthenticationMethods publickey,publickey
```

requires successful authentication using two different public keys.

### Note

A comma (`,`) separator symbol that separates a pair of auth options are tried together (AND-logic) firstly before any of its space separator(s).

A whitespace ( ) separator symbol that separates one or more auth options (whose options may be joined by comma(s)) are tried separately (OR-logic).

NOTE: Colon (`:`) separator are used to restrict its accompanied authentication method to a specific authentication device pathway mechanism such as `pam`, `bsdauth`, and `skey`. For keyboard interactive authentication it is also possible to restrict authentication to a specific device by appending a colon followed by the device identifier `bsdauth`, `pam`, or `skey`, depending on the server configuration. For example, `keyboard-interactive:bsdauth` would restrict keyboard
interactive authentication to the `bsdauth` device.

Note that each authentication option (except `none`) listed in `AuthenticationMethods` should also have its corresponding config setting be explicitly enabled in the configuration.  For example, if `pubkey` option got used in `AuthenticationMethods` setting then it’s accompanied config line `PubkeyAuthentication on` must also be in its config file.

### Details for code reviewers of OpenSSH

- Channel type: preauth (pre-channel)
- CLI option: -oAuthenticationMethods=XXXX"
- Process context: main
- SSH service: ssh-userauth (SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST)
- options.auth_methods[]/auth2_setup_methods_lists()/input_userauth_request()
- AuthenticationMethods defaults to '`any`'.